# Declare a List and populate with values using one code statement

Tags: c#, .net, list, initializer

I have following code

```
var list = new List<IMyCustomType>();
list.Add(new MyCustomTypeOne());
list.Add(new MyCustomTypeTwo());
list.Add(new MyCustomTypeThree());
```

this of course works, but I'm wondering: how can I declare the list and populate it with values using one statement?

Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx -1 for not using documentation. ;)

Comment: Well, you can just put `var list = new List<IMyCustomType>();
list.Add(new MyCustomTypeOne());
list.Add(new MyCustomTypeTwo());
list.Add(new MyCustomTypeThree());` on one line. Or did you mean *one statement*.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan :) one statement, ofcourse

Comment: But that's not what you said. Be precise. Please do edit the question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
var list = new List<IMyCustomType>{ 
    new MyCustomTypeOne(), 
    new MyCustomTypeTwo(), 
    new MyCustomTypeThree() 
};
```

Edit: Asker changed "one line" to "one statement", and this looks nicer.

Answer (score 9):

```
var list = new List<IMyCustomType>
{
   new MyCustomTypeOne(),
   new MyCustomTypeTwo(),
   new MyCustomTypeThree()
};
```

Not quite sure why you want it in one line?

Answer (score 3):

use the collection initialiser

```
var list = new List<IMyCustomType>
{
   new MyCustomTypeOne(){Properties should be given here},
   new MyCustomTypeTwo(){Properties should be given here},
   new MyCustomTypeThree(){Properties should be given here},
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [collection initializor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx):

```
var list = new List<IMyCustomType>() { new MyCustomTypeOne(), new MyCustomTypeTwo(), new MyCustomTypeThree() };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<IMyCustomType>{ new MyCustomTypeOne(), new  MyCustomTypeTwo() };
```